# rails 3.2.rc2 with node.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i tried to migrate my project from rails 3.0.6 to rails 3.2.rc2.
I found a lot of changes.one change seems to be node.js as javascript runtime.
whats the advantages on having node.js on  it.By having node.js.
is it possible to migrate the rails lower version to the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.1 (and later) uses javascript runtime to compile CoffeeScript assets to javascript. You don't have to have node.js, there are other supported javascript runtimes.